# chart.js npm module not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, chart.js

i just installed chart.js through npm. I am trying to use the package to draw graphs with it.

```
npm install chart.js --save
```

after installing, i tried to import the module with :

```
import chart from 'Chartjs';
```

but its not working, i am getting errors !

i have also tried:

```
import chart from 'Chart';
import chart from 'chart';
import chart from 'Chart-js';
```

none of them is working , how do i import this library ?

Comment: try " import chart from 'chart.js'; "

Comment: @PaoloMangia i tried it, it did'nt work

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: @PaoloMangia ok i have seen my mistake, its working now.....thanks !!!

Comment: @MazinoSUkah Consider posting your solution to others.

Comment: @russdot i have posted the solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @russdot, In case anyone is still having same issue,i solved this problem by importing it like this

```
import chart from 'chart.js';
```

cheers!!